# Apache mysql library cannot load

Tags: mysql, apache, ddl

Hello I have a problem with loading library mysql_php.dll. On localhost everything is OK, but when I copy my apache, php, mysql to my server (win server 2012) apache cannot load only mysql_php.dll (file exist in current path). Path to file is OK (because it can load openssl library from same path etc. only mysql library cant). I try everything what I find on internet like copy libmysql.dll to C:/Windows/system32 but still not working. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your log?

Comment: maybe the library is not compatible with server win2012?

Comment: What do you mean with "when I copy my apache, php, mysql to my server "? You copied the binaries and expect that to work?

Comment: @arkascha no i create new service for apache, db etc. everything working but apache cannot load only this library

Comment: @BartFriederichs Yes, Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/www/apache2/php5/ext/php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Comment: And, is that module there at that exact place? (Note you write `mysql_php.dll` in your question and the log says `php_mysql.dll`).

Comment: Ye sorry my mistake, ye is there like php_mysql.dll

Comment: Check permissions then. The webserver should have read access to that file and its directory.

Comment: This looks like one more example of the issues cause by the lack of any software management system on MS-Windows based systems. I wonder why MS does not introduce such thing which is common and helpful on all other platforms and reliably prevents such issues.